# Classie undefined, how to bring anonymous objects in scope with dojo AMD

Tags: javascript, dojo, js-amd, classiejs

I have this code:

```
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

    function classReg( className ) {
        return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
    }

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
    var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

    if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
        hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return elem.classList.contains( c );
        };
        addClass = function( elem, c ) {
            elem.classList.add( c );
        };
        removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
            elem.classList.remove( c );
        };
    }
    else {
        hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
        };
        addClass = function( elem, c ) {
            if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
                elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
            }
        };
        removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
            elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
        };
    }

    function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
        var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
        fn( elem, c );
    }

    var classie = {
        // full names
        hasClass: hasClass,
        addClass: addClass,
        removeClass: removeClass,
        toggleClass: toggleClass,
        // short names
        has: hasClass,
        add: addClass,
        remove: removeClass,
        toggle: toggleClass
    };

// transport
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // AMD
        define(classie );
    } else {
        // browser global
        window.classie = classie;
    }

})( window );
```

When I insert the dojo toolkit which has AMD, define( classie ); is called and when I try to use the classie object like so: classie.hasClass(document.getElementById('some_element'), 'some_class')
I receive an error in the console telling me "Uncaught ReferenceError: classie is not defined"

I have been searching and reading about Async Module Definition in Dojo and I am not able to find how to handle anonymous defined modules, how to require them or what I need to run to get it in the place I need it.

If I remove Dojo the code works because the variable can be found globaly in window.classie or just by classie itself.

I am also using another library https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/blob/master/mobile-detect.js which has the same issue as classie.

I do not want to change these js libraries, what am I doing wrong on my part when I am trying to use these defined objects with AMD?

Edit:
Here is the stripped version of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.9/dojo/dojo.js"
data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

    function classReg( className ) {
        return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
    }

    // classList support for class management
    // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
    var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

    if (false && 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
        hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return 1;
        };
        addClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return 1;
        };
        removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return 1;
        };
    }
    else {
        hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return 1;
        };
        addClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return 1;
        };
        removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
            return 1;
        };
    }

    function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
        return 1;
    }

    var classie = {
        // full names
        hasClass: hasClass,
        addClass: addClass,
        removeClass: removeClass,
        toggleClass: toggleClass,
        // short names
        has: hasClass,
        add: addClass,
        remove: removeClass,
        toggle: toggleClass
    };

    // transport
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // AMD
        define( classie );
    } else {
        // browser global
        window.classie = classie;
    }

})( window );

// test object
alert(classie.hasClass(document.getElementById('some_element'), 'some_class'));
</script>
<div id="some_element"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a better idea (as in, more context than a single line) of how/where you are attempting to use these libraries, to help provide a basis for an answer/solution.

Comment: Here is a stripped version of what I am trying to achive, if you remove the dojo library it works as expected, I am inserting this code on different websites to do some tracking and you can imagine they have different libraries, in this case they have a dojo js library. The question is how do I use a defined literal object with AMD?

Comment: Why not using dojo/dom-class ? it does what you need and you don't have to mess with AMD ;)

Comment: @ben thank you for taking the time to answer, as I said previously I will insert this script on other websites, which use different libraries, it is not a matter of what js library I use, the problem is that this and another library are defining literal objects with AMD and I do not know how to use this objects defined in this way and the only solution at this time would be to re-write those libraries, I would like to avoid that.